# When Jesus talks about the writings of Moses, which texts does he mean?

Tags: john, moses

We read:

> For if you believed Moses, you would believe Me;  for he wrote about
> Me. But if you  do not believe his writings, how will you believe My
> words?” John 5:46-47

**Q**: **Is there any way to interpret what our Lord meant by “Moses’s writings”? How do we know what his writings are?**

Comment: Moses' corpus consists of the Torah + Ps 90.  Do you doubt that?

Comment: @Dottard I don’t doubt it, but in terms of understanding the historical background for Jesus’s assertion that Moses wrote of Him, how do we compile such evidence?  Example: (Ancient Jewish writings outside the scripture, internal witnesses in the Scripture itself, etc).  Also, I wasn’t aware Moses wrote Psalms 90 until you mentioned it, thanks!

Comment: @Dottard Apparently after doing a more thorough investigation on (Bible Gateway) I found some verses, one of which is: And Moses wrote all the words of the Lord. And he rose early in the morning, and built an altar at the foot of the mountain, and twelve pillars according to the twelve tribes of Israel.”
Exodus 24:4

Comment: Somewhat related observation: there are multiple examples in OT & NT (and a few in the Patristics too) where a sacred/authoritative writing is quoted or referenced but we don't have it today. So we could say that Moses wrote *at a minimum* the majority of the first 5 books, plus a Psalm, without ruling out the possibility that he wrote other things that have not survived

Comment: @HoldToTheRod Can you send a link or a link for a book to point me in the right direction?  I have “The Canon of Scripture, by F.F. Bruce” but I haven’t read it yet due to the other books I am reading.

Comment: @Cork88 -  FF Bruce is an insightful scholar! I don't have a specific book I could recommend re my comment above, it was just more of an observation about the open nature of the question *what did Moses write*?

Answer (score 3):

Yes, and it's the best link you could ever get, as detailed in the Bible. Remember the account of two disciples walking to a village called Emmaus, talking about the death of Christ? We are told that Jesus drew near, and joined their company, but their eyes were not opened to see that this was the resurrected Christ. They expressed astonishment at this apparent stranger asking what had recently happened in Jerusalem. So, they related the crucifixion and how some women saw the empty tomb and an angel who said that Christ was alive.

At that point, Jesus said:

> "O fools, and slow of heart to believe all that the prophets have
> spoken. Ought not Christ to have suffered these things, and to enter
> into his glory?" And beginning at Moses and all the prophets, he
> expounded to them in all the scriptures the things concerning
> himself... As he sat at meat with them, he took bread, and blessed it,
> and brake, and gave to them. And their eyes were opened, and they knew
> him: and he vanished out of their sight.
>
> And they said one to another, Did not our heart burn within us, while
> he talked with us by the way, and while he opened to us the
> scriptures?" (Luke 24:13-32)

Notice how Jesus explained not only what Moses had written about himself, but what all the prophets (in the Old Testament) had prophesied about Christ? This means that the more familiar a person is with Moses and the prophets (in the Hebrew scriptures) the easier it should be for them to grasp how Jesus is the Christ. Yet the critical factor is having one's spiritual eyes opened to see what the scriptures foretold about Messiah. But it has to start with the Hebrew scriptures, and all the prophecies, of which there are 360 of the Messiah; of these, 109 are mathematically impossible to have been fulfilled by any person other than Jesus.

The apostle Peter quoted from the Hebrew scriptures about that:

> "This is how God fulfilled what he had foretold through all the
> prophets, saying that his Christ would suffer.... For Moses said, 'The
> Lord your God will raise up for you a prophet like me from among your
> own people; you must listen to everything he tells you'... Indeed all
> the prophets from Samuel on, as many as have spoken, have foretold
> these days..." and so on. Acts 3:18-26

At Jesus' transfiguration on the mountain, God spoke to the 3 disciples present, commanding them to listen to Jesus, His Son. That was God identifying Jesus as the foretold prophet greater than Moses - Matthew 17:5.

The Christian martyr Stephen also said to his Jewish accusers, "This is that Moses who told the Israelites, 'God will send you a prophet like me from your own people'...(Deuteronomy 18:15)" and identified that one as Jesus of Nazareth, resurrected from the dead as proof that He is the Son of God. Acts 7:37 & Romans 1:1-6

So, there are a few scripture links in the Bible to get you started. **This link gives the kind of information you need to pursue this matter of Mosaic, and other Old Testament prophecies about Jesus.**
https://www.gotquestions.org/prophecies-of-Jesus.html

Answer (score 0):

It would appear that God wanted Moses to make writings, this is how we can interpret Jesus’s words in John’s gospel.

Here are a few Scriptures to consider:

> These are the journeys of the children of Israel, who went out of the
> land of Egypt by their armies under the hand of Moses and Aaron. Now
> **Moses wrote down** the starting points of their journeys **at the command
> of the Lord**. And these are their journeys according to their starting
> points: **Numbers 33:1-2**
>
> And **Moses wrote** ***all*** **the words of the Lord**. And he rose early in the
> morning, and built an altar at the foot of the mountain, and twelve
> pillars according to the twelve tribes of Israel.
> **Exodus 24:4**
>
> So **Moses wrote this law** and delivered it to the priests, the sons
> of Levi, who bore the ark of the covenant of the Lord, and to all the
> elders of Israel.
> **Deuteronomy 31:9**

Genesis & Leviticus I have yet to research the attribution to Moses.  Maybe somebody else can fill in that evidence.